# macos minikube unsupported driver: kvm2

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

Hi do you know why I get the following error:

```
  ~ minikube start --vm-driver kvm2             
  minikube v1.0.0 on darwin (amd64)
  Downloading Kubernetes v1.14.0 images in the background ...
  Creating kvm2 VM (CPUs=2, Memory=2048MB, Disk=20000MB) ...
  unsupported driver: kvm2
```

I have installed:

```
brew update && brew install kubernetes-cli && brew cask install docker docker-machine minikube virtualbox && brew install hyperkit
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [Minikube Driver Plugin Installation](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/docs/drivers.md#driver-plugin-installation):

> Minikube uses Docker Machine to manage the Kubernetes VM so it
>   benefits from the driver plugin architecture that Docker Machine uses
>   to provide a consistent way to manage various VM providers. Minikube
>   embeds VirtualBox and VMware Fusion drivers so there are no additional
>   steps to use them. However, other drivers require an extra binary to
>   be present in the host PATH.

The KVM2 driver is maintained by the minikube team. It is built, tested and released with minikube, however, [it's **not supported by MacOS**](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/docs/drivers.md#kvm2-driver).

*(I'm assuming that you are using MacOS since you are managing your packages with `brew`).*

Minikube supports the [following drivers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/minikube/#quickstart) (set with `--vm-driver=xxxxx`; default is `virtualbox`):

> - virtualbox
> - vmwarefusion
> - kvm2
> - kvm
> - hyperkit
> - xhyve (deprecated)
> - hyperv
> - none (Runs the Kubernetes components on the host and not in a VM. Using this driver requires Docker and a Linux environment

From this list, the best suitable drivers to use with MacOS are:

- [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)
- [VMware Fusion](https://www.vmware.com/products/fusion.html)
- *and maybe the [Hyperkit driver](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/docs/drivers.md#hyperkit-driver)*

Comment: I am using CentOs but getting the same unsupported error. Can you help?